# Class Member Not a Reference but Constructor with Argument Passed by Reference

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference, copy-constructor, pass-by-value

What happens when you have something like this in C++:

```
class foo {
public:
   foo(obj &b);
   obj a;
};

foo::foo(b) : a(b) {}
```

Are the values inside `b` copied to `a`? Or since `b` is reference, then the reference of `b` is assigned to `a`?

Comment: If your code were fixed to make it actually compilable, then yes, `a` would be a copy of `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the same as the following code:

```
void foo(obj& b) {
    obj a(b);
}
```

It copies (copy-constructs) the `b` object to `a`.

Comment: is that a yes for all the values in b being copied to a?

Comment: @mkmostafa, this depends on how the copy constructor of `obj` is implemented.

Comment: is there a way to update my code to make b assigned to a by reference?

Comment: @mkmostafa, why not declare `a` as a reference?

Comment: because I want to have the liberty of leaving it a NULL, or initialing it later. Reference members do not allow that.

Comment: can you take a look at my comment below? :D on vlad's reply.

Comment: @mkmostafa, I'm afraid you have no other possibility. And it is not clear why you do not want to use a pointer. Anyway, the discussion seems to drift from the question as it is stated. If you want, you may ask a separate question concerning your design problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the class definition

```
class foo {
   foo(obj &b);
   obj a;
};
```

data member `a` is not a reference.  So in this constructor the data member is initialized by the value of the object referenced by `b`.

```
foo::foo(b) : a(b) {}
```

On the other hand if the class would be defined like

```
class foo {
   foo(obj &b);
   obj &a;
};
```

where `a` is a reference then in this constructor

```
foo::foo(b) : a(b) {}
```

`a` would refer the object that in turn is referenced by `b`.

Comment: yea, the problem is I dont want to have a class member as reference because of the restrictions it brings. I wanted to have the best of both as in to be able to initialize the member at anytime and in the same time if I passed a reference to the object, I didn't want the whole values to be copied!

I also want to avoid pointers! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a [constructor initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), which:

> Specifies the initializers for direct and virtual base subobjects and non-static data members

**EDIT:**

Internally this simply [copy constructs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) `a`, which would be defined in `class obj` as either: `obj(obj&)` or `obj(const obj&)`.

If `obj` has *no user defined constructors* the compiler will [implicitly declare a copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor) which will:

> Performs full member-wise copy of the object's bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using direct initialization.

Comment: my question is what happens internally? are the values of b copied to a? or is it just a reference assignment?

Comment: @mkmostafa Sorry I misunderstood the question. I've given a link and added the relevant text on what a copy constructor does. Incidentally it's probably worth your time to do a little study on [move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) as well which were introduced at C++11.

Answer (score 0):

A copy occurs `obj & b` allows a reference to the object to be passed in, saving a copy.

However in the constructor the effect is `obj a = b;` a copy constructor on `obj` is called.

Comment: so in the end the values of b are copied to a?

Comment: Yes `a` is initialized by a call to the copy-constructor ( `obj::obj( const & rhs )` ).  This is when `a` is initialized, and it is invoked with `obj a(  b );`

Answer (score 0):

Think about the code:

```
obj o;
foo f(o);
```

When `foo::foo` is called, the parameter is passed by reference, so `o` would *not* be copied to the parameter `b`. And then:

```
foo::foo(b) : a(b) {}
```

Because the member variable `a` is not defined as a reference, so `b` will be copied to `a`, i.e. the copy ctor of `obj` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

It's at times like these that I reach into my handy git repo of little test programs and pull out my object lifetime tracker:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    A()
    {
        cout << "Created " << describe() << endl;
    }

    A(A&& r)
    : ident(r.ident)
    {
        r.zombie = true;
        cout << "Move-constructed " << describe() << endl;
    }
    A(const A& r)
    {
        cout << "copy-constructed " << describe() << " from " << r.describe() << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "destroyed " << describe() << endl;
    }

    A& operator=(A&& r) {
        cout << describe() << " is being move-assigned from " << r.describe() << endl;
        ident = r.ident;
        zombie = false;
        r.zombie = true;
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator=(const A&r ) {
        cout << describe() << " is being assigned from " << r.describe() << endl;
        zombie = false;
        return *this;
    }

    string describe() const {
        return (zombie ? "zombie "s : "object "s) + to_string(ident);
    }

    size_t ident = next_ident();
    bool zombie = false;

    static size_t next_ident() {
        static size_t ident = 0;
        return ident++;
    }
};


class foo {
public:
    foo(const A &b) : a(b) {}
    foo(A &&b) : a(move(b)) {}
    A a;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    A a;
    foo f(a);
    foo f2(move(a));
    A a2;
    f = a2;
    f2 = move(a2);

    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
Created object 0
copy-constructed object 1 from object 0
Move-constructed object 0
Created object 2
copy-constructed object 3 from object 2
object 1 is being move-assigned from object 3
destroyed zombie 3
Move-constructed object 2
object 0 is being move-assigned from object 2
destroyed zombie 2
destroyed zombie 2
destroyed object 2
destroyed object 3
destroyed zombie 0
```